How can I update a CloudFormation stack in the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state?
I assigned a stack policy to my stack to prevent updates and deletes:
{
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Deny",
      "NotAction" : ["Update:Replace", "Update:Delete"],
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*"
    }
  ]
}

When I try to update the stack, it's rejected due to the stack policy, and the stack is set to the 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE' state. Then, when I update the stack policy to allow updating:
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}

and try to continue the rollback, I get the following error:
aws cloudformation continue-update-rollback --stack-name --resources-to-skip

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ContinueUpdateRollback operation: RollbackUpdatedStack cannot be called from current stack status

I also can't click on the functions 'Cancel update stack' or 'continue update rollback' in the management console:
stack
Can anyone help me with this problem?

You cannot roll it back (continue-update-rollback) because it's already in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state. Since you already updated your permission, just try to update it again.

You have to update the stack again instead of doing a continue rollback.

For a specified stack that's in the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state,
continues rolling it back to the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state.
Depending on the cause of the failure, you can manually fix the error
and continue the rollback. By continuing the rollback, you can return
your stack to a working state (the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state),
and then try to update the stack again.
A stack goes into the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state when AWS
CloudFormation can't roll back all changes after a failed stack
update. For example, you might have a stack that's rolling back to an
old database instance that was deleted outside of AWS CloudFormation.
Because AWS CloudFormation doesn't know the database was deleted, it
assumes that the database instance still exists and attempts to roll
back to it, causing the update rollback to fail.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ContinueUpdateRollback.html

